# Write Tab Delimited txt file from c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having some problem writing a tab delimited string into a txt file.

```
//This is the result I want:    
First line. Second line.    nThird line.

//But I'm getting this:
First line./tSecond line./tThird line.
```

Below is my code where I pass the string to be written into the txt file:

```
string word1 = "FirstLine.";
string word2 = "SecondLine.";
string word3 = "ThirdLine.";
string line = word1 + "/t" + word2 + "/t" + word3;

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true);
file.WriteLine(line);

file.Close();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\t` for the tab character. Using `String.Format` may present a more readable option:

```
line = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", word1, word2, word3);
```

Answer (score 5):

To write a tab character you need to use `"\t"`. It's a backslash (above the enter key), not a forward slash.

So your code should read:

```
string line = word1 + "\t" + word2 + "\t" + word3;
```

For what it's worth, here is a list of common "escape sequences" like `"\t" = TAB`:

- [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use `\t` not `/t` for tab in the string. so your string `line` should be:

```
string line = word1 + "\t" + word2 + "\t" + word3;
```

if you do:

```
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

output would be:

```
FirstLine.      SecondLine.     ThirdLine.
```